# Array of pointers to strings printing null

Tags: c, xv6

I'm learning C in a restricted OS (xv6) that only has a subset of C. I'm trying split a single string into an array of strings.

To do that, I've constructed an array of pointers to strings `lines`. My expectation is that lines will end up looking like this:
`lines = { "abc", "def", "ghi" }`

When I try to access lines by index (e.g. lines[0]) I'm getting `null`. I'm stumped why I'm getting null and have tried several things. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something very obvious.

*Note: Not looking for working code, as I would like to continue building this myself, but would appreciate some guidance on why I'm getting this result.*

```
#define STDIN 0
#define STDOUT 1

static void readline(){
    char buff[] = "abc\ndef\nghi";
    int i,j;
    char current[20];
    char *lines[20];
    int counter = -1;
    int lines_counter = -1;
    for(i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
        if(buff[i] == '\n' || buff[i] == '\0'){
            lines_counter++;
            for(j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                lines[lines_counter][j] = current[j];
            }
            counter = -1;
        } else {
          current[++counter] = buff[i];
        }
    }
    printf(STDOUT, "%s", lines[0]); // expected "aaa", instead output is(null)
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    readline(); 
    exit();
}
```

Comment: `lines[lines_counter][j]` is also uninitialised memory access.

Comment: In other words `lines` is an array of 20 pointers, each which point nowhere and are currently uninitialized. You must assign valid storage to a pointer before you can start storing characters there. You assign storage either by dynamically allocating storage for each pointer with `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`, or by assigning the starting address for an existing array to each pointer. (**note:** you can have each pointer in lines point to a different existing character within `buf` and then replace the `'\n'`s in buf with `'\0'` and use `buf` as your existing storage)

Comment: FYI, neither `counter` no `lines_counter` need to be initialized to -1, nor reset to said-same, if you structured your loop(s) with a greater degree of sanity. In fact, it will make the code easier to write, and read, if you figure out how starting at zero, and when to increment each/either, should be done. Regardless, this code was *Botn* to run in a debugger, single-stepping and watching variables/memory to understand what you wrote is doing, and thus how it differs from what you intended.

Comment: To use the %s format specifier the string must be null terminated. So you have to append  '\0' char.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That was exactly the issue. Thank you for the tip, I come from a higher level language that doesn't require explicit memory allocation. I took the time to learn more about malloc, calloc and realloc.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise just looking at the source code of `strtok` and try expanding any standard library calls. `strchr` is just a search for a char in a string and `strcspn` just counts the number of characters before `strchr` returns.